# redis/phpredis on laravel with cluster on Elasticache

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, predis

I've seen a number of articles that address this issue, but none of them seem to be marked as solutions, and none of them work. I have a redis cluster set up on AWS Elasticache and I'm trying to get it working with Laravel. I am able to connect fine using `redis-cli` from my app server so I know everything is accessible.

Laravel gives me an error:

```
Predis \ Response \ ServerException
MOVED 9970 <ip>:6379
```

My AWS configuration is as follows:

```
Engine Version Compatibility: 6.0.5
Number of Nodes: 9 nodes
Shards: 3
Auto-failover: enabled
Multi-AZ: disabled
```

My Laravel configuration is:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'phpredis',
        'cluster' => true,

        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '<cache-name>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
                'password' => null,
                'port' => 6379,
                'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => '<cache-name>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
            'password' => null,
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
            'parameters' => [
                'password' => null,
                'scheme' => 'tcp',
            ],
            'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false],
        ],
]
```

Comment: Reading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#configuring-clusters the option `clusters.default` should be an array of hosts not a single host

Comment: It is indeed. I just solved this. :) It's not obvious, I was going by examples from google searches whereby the clusters array was either not populated, or in the one example of clusters I did see they didn't have the array of hosts either. I spent hours searching for the answer and it turned out to be so simple. Even though I could have read the docs a bit closer, I feel the docs could have explicitly mentioned the addition of that extra array inside the connection as they have an identical example further up the page without the inner array!